# Porque esta função esta entrando em loop infinito?

Tags: php

Fiz esta função para retornar um código unico ( ele verifica se já existe buscando num webservice), porem quando executo, ele fica executando para sempre, não me retorna resultado.

```
public function generateuniquecode(){
    function generatecode(){
      $upper = implode('', range('A', 'Z')); // ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
      $nums = implode('', range(0, 9)); // 0123456789
      $alphaNumeric = $upper.$nums; // ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789
      $code = '';
      for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
          $code .= $alphaNumeric[rand(0, strlen($alphaNumeric) - 1)];
      }
      return $code; // ex: X0XX0X
    }
    $exists = false;
    while($exists == false) {
      $code = generatecode();
      $response = $this->seachcardbycode($code);
      if($response['success'] == false){
        if($response['data']['code'] == 1){
          $exists = false;
        }else{
          die('code 0');
          // code 0
          // curl call error
        }
      }else{
        $exists = true;
      }
    }
    return $code; 
  }
```

A função seachcardbycode retorna um array assim:

```
array(
      "success"=>false / true,
      "data"=>outro array
    );
```

Comment: Já tentou fazer a impressão dos objetos que o `$response` faz referência?

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente o problema se encontra no seu código, no trecho onde inicia o IF.

```
if($response['success'] == false)
```

Para ser mais preciso na resposta seria interessante você postar o código de toda a função o `seachcardbycode`.
Para ver as possibilidades do valor de `$response['success']` ser alterado.
A principio esta vindo sempre com o valor **false** assim o **else** nunca será acionado, e o valor de `$existes` nunca será alterado.

Caso não seja passado para `$response` nenhum objeto onde **success** for igual a **false**, realmente vai ficar em um loop infinito este código.